# Creating an ant task interleaving .java and .class files in a .jar?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I created the java project in Eclipse with separate src and bin folders. Now I want a .jar which has them combined in the same folder, just like .jardesc does. I created an ant script which looks like this:

```
<project name="build-jar" default="build-jar" basedir=".">
    <target name="build-jar">
        <jar destfile="test.jar"
             basedir="."
            includes="**/*.java **/*.class"
            update="true"
        />
    </target>
</project>
```

But this will create a .jar with bin/ and src/ folders. I want the top level folders all to be the actual packages already and the .class files interleaved with the .java files. How can I achieve that?

EDIT: Current non-working, modified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="build-jar" default="build-jar">
    <target name="build-jar">
        <jar destfile="test.jar" update="true">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="bin">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about jar up both directories at once using fileset?

```
<jar destfile="test.jar" update="true">
    <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="bin">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</jar>
```

Comment: David, that still generates bin and src folders in the resulting .jar and .class and .java are still separated in them

Comment: Omit the basedir="." from the jar task, otherwise it'll try to build relative paths into the jar.

Comment: That doesn't work either, are you sure this exact code is working for you? I'll update the post with what exactly I'm using now

Comment: I'm positive that works - I just ran your updated build.xml and got a test.jar with the layout you expect - no src or bin anywhere in it.  How are you running ant?  What version is it?  Maybe post your project directory layout too?

Comment: Ok this was weird, it was literally working with every name except test.jar. I ran it with testt.jar and it worked. Then I run the same ant task 10 times in a row, and suddenly, magically, the correct layout appeared with test.jar. Some kind of filesystem cache? Doesn't make sense to me, but your answer is definitely correct, thank you.

Comment: @Blub : since the jar is now set to "update", you should delete it before the first update.  Otherwise it will have the old content with new.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it after every try. Still somehow it didn't work with that one name. Oh well, now it does.